# how to display content below fullscreen background video

Tags: html, css, video, fullscreen

I'm designing a landing page where i have a background video in fullscreen and then when the user scrolls down there is content below the video. 
I've managed to kind of get it to work by setting the content to have a top margin of 100vh but there is a huge gap between the video and the content...

HTML

```
  <body>
  <div class="bgvid-back">
  <video class="bgvid" poster="media/skyline.jpg" autoplay="true" loop muted width="100%">
      <source src="media/BnW.webm" type="video/webm">
      <source src="media/BnW.mp4" type="video/mp4">      
  </video>
  </div> 
  <ul class="menu">
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="navburger" data-toggle="offCanvasLeft">
                <div class="one"></div>
                <div class="two"></div>
                <div class="three"></div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="logo"><img src="media/rsz_lucidity-logo.png"></a></li>
    </ul>
  <p class="content"> lorum ipsum </p>
  </body>
```

CSS

```
.bgvid-back {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: -100;
} 

.bgvid {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
width: auto;
height: auto;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
.bgvid-back {
    background: url("media/skyline.jpg") center center / cover no-repeat;
}

.fullscreen-bg__video {
    display: none;
}
}
.content {
background-color: #313638;
margin: 100vh 0 0 0;
width: 100vh;
}
```

this is what it looks like atm:

[vid shows in fullscreen as background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7xuM.jpg)

[when scrolled down can see content but there is a large gap although margin-top: 100vh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekCCT.jpg)

thanks in advance for any help :)

im a bit of a novice to css so appologies if this is obvious.

Comment: 1. your image doesn't work. upload it here directly. 2. in your html there is not `.content` div. Please make a working snippet with your problem ( there is a button with `<>` signs on it in your editor

Comment: @MihaiT sorry i forgot i changed that div. also re uploaded image. is that better?

Comment: you also have a menu, and that is what most likely is pushing the `.content` down as the margin will start from the `.menu` and not the `body`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the reason your content has a huge gap above it is because the menu is pushing the `100vh` top margin down. To fix it you are going to want to add something like the following CSS:

```
ul.menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

Once that's added your content should act normal. Let me know how it goes!